# Dynamic Build lambda with generic type

Tags: c#, lambda

How to build dynamic lambda function like below?

```
item => item.AnalyzeData.Any(subitem => 
subitem.DepartmentIDs.Any(subitem2 => subitem2 == "abc"))
```

1. `AnalyzeData` is custom class array type, `DepartmentIDs` is string array type
2. The class of `AnalyzeData` has `DepartmentIDs` Property

So how to dynamic generator the above lambda expression via expression tree.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, the problem has been resolved. now share the solution code to others who has the some issue.

```
    [TestMethod]
    [Description("Dynamic generate lambda expression")]

    public void DynamicGenerateMethod1()
    {
        Item item1 = new Item()
                        {
                            ItemID = "test1",
                            AnalyzeData = new ItemAnalyzeData[]
                                              {
                                                  new ItemAnalyzeData()
                                                      {
                                                          DepartmentIDs = new []{"Department1","Department2"}
                                                      }, 
                                              }
                        };
        Item item2 = new Item()
        {
            ItemID = "test2",
            AnalyzeData = new ItemAnalyzeData[]
                                              {
                                                  new ItemAnalyzeData()
                                                      {
                                                          DepartmentIDs = new []{"Department3","Department4"}
                                                      }, 
                                              }
        };


        Expression<Func<Item, bool>> expectedExpression =
            item => item.AnalyzeData.Any(subitem => subitem.DepartmentIDs.Any(subitem2 => subitem2 == "Department3"));
        //Get Enumerable.Any generic method
        var anyPredicate =
            typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);



        #region Build inner most lambda expression : subitem2 => subitem2 == "Department3"

        var subitem2Para = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "subitem2");
        var subitem2CompareValue = Expression.Equal(subitem2Para, Expression.Constant("Department3", typeof(string)));
        var subitem2CompareFun = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(subitem2CompareValue, subitem2Para);

        #endregion

        #region Build center lambda expression : subitem => subitem.DepartmentIDs.Any( ... )

        var subitemPara = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ItemAnalyzeData), "subitem");
        var departmentIDsAnyMethodCall = anyPredicate.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
        var subItemDepartmentIDsCall = Expression.Call(departmentIDsAnyMethodCall, Expression.Property(subitemPara, "DepartmentIDs"), subitem2CompareFun);
        var subitemCompareFun = Expression.Lambda<Func<ItemAnalyzeData, bool>>(subItemDepartmentIDsCall, subitemPara);

        #endregion

        #region Build outer most lambda expression : item => item.AnalyzeData.Any( ... )

        var itemExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "item");
        var analyzeAnyMethodCall = anyPredicate.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(ItemAnalyzeData));
        var itemAnalyzeDataCall = Expression.Call(analyzeAnyMethodCall, Expression.Property(itemExpr, "AnalyzeData"), subitemCompareFun);
        var itemCompareFun = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(itemAnalyzeDataCall, itemExpr);

        #endregion

        var method = itemCompareFun.Compile();

        var actualLambdaCode = itemCompareFun.ToString();
        var expectLambdaCode = expectedExpression.ToString();
        Assert.AreEqual(expectLambdaCode, actualLambdaCode);
        Assert.IsFalse(method.Invoke(item1));
        Assert.IsTrue(method.Invoke(item2));




    }
```